# In Call Status Bar does not cause parent UIViewController to resize

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

I have a UIViewController that correctly resizes itself when the In-Call Status Bar appears. Additionally, this presents a child UIViewController which also correctly resizes itself. However, if I present the child VC and show the in-call status bar, after dismissing the child, the parent VC is not sized like the in-call bar is showing. If I hide and re-show the status bar, the parent will resize itself correctly. How can I make it so the parent VC will already be sized correctly when dismissing the child?

Example:

Parent.m

```
[self.view addSubview:self.webView];
self.webView.autoresizesSubviews = YES;
//The webview resizes correctly when in-call status bar shows
self.childViewController = [[Child alloc]init];
//present child
[self presentViewController:self.childViewController animated:YES completion:nil];

//In-call status bar shows (child resizes correctly)

[self.childViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
//View is still sized as if in-call status bar is not shown
```

Child.m

```
self.view.autoresizesSubviews = YES;
[self.view setAutoresizingMask:(UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth)];
//The view resizes correctly when in-call status bar shows
```

Comment: Question Review : Add a simplified version of the code that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: @RichLinnell added. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately I was unable to fix this issue. Instead, I switched from presenting and dismissing the child view controller to pushing and popping it as a navigation item. The only real difference I've noticed is that the animation is different (the child animates from the right instead of from the bottom), but other than that it seems to be effectively the same, and the issue with the in-call status bar resolved itself.